# C++ Operator overloading error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘float’ and ‘Class’)

Tags: c++, overloading, istream

I'm working on some OOP code and was trying to setup a `istream&` with the `operator >>`. But with the code that I have, I keep getting an error, like the one stated above in the title. The code I have to do this is:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Forward& fwd){
    in >> fwd.value;
    cerr << "Value in forward is: " << fwd.value;

    return in;
}
```

This code is part of the `Forward` class and `value` is a member variable of the base class called `Command`, which `Forward` is inheriting from.

I then tried to use this operator in a different class, the `Program` class:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Program& prog){
    float value = 4;
    Forward *temp = new Forward();
    value >> *temp;
}
```

But this gave me the errors:

> error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘float’ and ‘Forward’)

and

> no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘float’ to ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}’

Note: I need to keep the line `Forward *temp = new Forward();` because it is used a lot in the code.

Comment: I suspect there is a bug somewhere in the code not provided.  Could you provide a [mcve]?  Emphasis on *minimal*, and *complete* (so we can copy-paste and compile your code verbatim), and *example* (reproduces your issue)?

Comment: Your `>>` for `Program` doesn't make any sense. You don't use *either* of the parameters. Does a `Program` have a `Forward` member?

Comment: "Note: I need to keep the line Forward *temp = new Forward(); because it is used a lot in the code." why not `Forward temp;`? You don't need `new` to create an instance of a class

Answer (score 1):

```
value >> *temp
```

Replace with

```
in >> *temp;
```

Comment: Sorry, value is the data I want to pass into the forward class. It is defined in the code and I've updated the question to show this.

Comment: What you need is `std::stringstream`. 
`std::stringstream stream; stream << value; stream >> *temp;`

Comment: Just to clarify, @Slash are you saying that in a statement `in >> prog` you want to completely ignore the contents of `in` and just create a new `Forward` with `value = 4`?

Comment: @Useless yes. I've left this block of code in the operator function of the program class because I was in a rush. Should I put this code somewhere else?

Comment: float variables cannot be cast to istream, you might want to rework your function if this is what you want - i.e. the >> operator as you defined it can only be used with data streams as inputs, such as files and sstream objects. Which means, you cannot call it with a float value as the left operand.

Comment: You might as well just write `new Forward{value}` or whatever then. Why are you trying to use an input streaming operator if you have no intention of taking any input from a stream?

Comment: @Useless was trying to learn how to use them (istreams) more effectively.

Comment: I don't think you can use input streams effectively by passing them to a function and then ignoring them! You really need to clarify (in you mind, and ideally also in the question) what the contents of the input stream are and how it's supposed to relate to the contents of `Prog` and `Forward`. Currently you have a collection of apparently-unrelated code...